# Run javascript from jQuery.ajax call

Tags: jquery

I am learning jQuery, so I'm attempting to write this simple demo. I've tried a variety of approaches and I've done searching here and elsewhere before resorting to posting this question.

I understand that $.ajax makes an xmlhttpRequest, which I am familiar with. That being the case, I thought it would work if I sent that to a PHP file where I could compute my result. Unfortunately, when I open tryjquery.html in my browser, the page just displays the word "error" in my "div" block. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Here's my code:

In tryjquery.html, I have a script section that calls this:

```
Calculator.addRemote(1,5,function(result){
$('div').html(result);
});
```

Calculator is this object:

```
function Calculator(){
this.addRemote = addRemote;
}

that = Calculator;
that.addRemote = function (a, b, completedHandler){

var post = $.ajax({
    url: "/Calculator/Add",
    data: {a: a, b: b},
    type: "POST"
});

   post.done(function (result) {
   completedHandler(result);  
   });  

   post.fail(function () {  
   completedHandler('error');  
   });  
}
```

...and /Calculator/Add is this php code:

```
<?php
$a = $_GET['a'];
$b = $_GET['b'];
$r = $a + $b;
echo "result=".$r.";";
?>
```

Comment: In PHP you're accessing `$_GET` array, while you use `AJAX POST` method. It's inconsistent.

Comment: Ahh. That is true. Thank you.
I have changed it; the result is the same however.

Comment: Then I have no other idea. You would have to post a link the script on you server. You can also do:
`post.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {  
   completedHandler('error');
   console.warn(jqXHR, textStatus);
});`

Comment: @Nezumi `that = Calculator;` is wrong, use `that = new Calculator();`

Comment: Miszy, I'm currently just using localhost.
I tried your new post.fail method. The inner html of div is now just empty.

webdeveloper: thank you. I've changed that.

I'm modeling my work on this blog post, by the way:
http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2012/05/async-ajax-testing-using-qunit.html

Comment: I checked the console; it displays this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object function Calculator(){
 this.addRemote = addRemote;
} has no method 'addRemote' 

Which I find cconfusing, since it looks like addRemote is defined. Or is it?

Comment: It seems the answer was just that I didn't have the directory /Calculator in the main directory T_T